# Build audio unit for osx 10.6 with Xcode 5

Tags: c++, xcode, sdk

I've written an Audio Unit in XCode 5, and I want it to work with Mac OS X 10.6 snow leopard.

I've added the Mac OS X 10.6 SDK to the Xcode 5 application bundle and changed the following in the Xcode project build settings:
Base SDK = OS X 10.6
OS X Deployment target = OS X 10.6

But I get this error when building:
clang: error: invalid deployment target for -stdlib=libc++ (requires OS X 10.7 or later)

What do I need to do to make this work?

Thanks in advance